# Custom error on failed parameter binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Normally on a web API action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<Item> Get(Guid ItemId){...}
```

If the HTTP request contains no ItemId parameter, it will return 400 Bad Request with an exception like

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ItemId' of non-nullable type...
```

Is there a way to provide a custom error message when this happens, rather than the exception message **without converting ItemId to a nullable type**?

Comment: What type are you returning? Post the whole Action. Did you consider returning a -1 in the ID in case there is no ID?

Comment: I can't return anything, because an exception is thrown before the action is even entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom filter attribute that will handle and return the proper response with a message as needed.

[Here is a great article on how to do so.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling#exception_filters)

Comment: I can't add logic to the action itself, because the action never starts. I don't want to redirect, because that makes no sense in this situation. I simply want to return a more user-friendly message "You must provide a valid ItemId"

Comment: Okay I understand. I do however have 1 question. Do you want to return a friendly looking view with the message or do you want to return an actual exception with a custom message?

Comment: This is a web API action, so I want to return a HTTP Response: `{Message:"..."}`